# How to detect device mode emulation?

Tags: javascript, webkit

Referring to Chrome's ability to emulate device resolution and touch events: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

The actual issue:

```
'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement
```

In device emulation mode returns `false` (when it is in fact capable of performing a touch event). Thus, I need an exception for the device mode emulation.

Comment: [This](https://frontify.com/blog/how-to-emulate-touch-events-in-chrome/) could be usefull for you.

Comment: I know how to emulate touch events. I am asking how to detect an environment thats emulating touch events.

Comment: Maybe you need to read it again ... as it  states that [FireFox OS](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/07/firefox-os-simulator-4-0-released/) came up with a tool to do just that. It's not in your favourite browser, so perhaps that's not possible.

Comment: Question is about Chrome's device emulation.

Answer (score 6):

You need to check for `ontouchstart` in window. Not document.documentElement.

Touch Events are to be detected with:

```
'TouchEvent' in window && 'ontouchstart' in window
```

I should mention that I am not including the `window.DocumentTouch` method used by Modernizr. It's only for Firefox < 25 and Mozilla dropped the Touch Metro UI on Windows. So I don't see any plausible or relevant browser usage to really justify it any longer. And while `TouchEvent in window` isn't required, I think it's more future proof and technically correct to check the API's presence too.

For more details on Touch Events detection see the latest [Modernizr Touch Event Feature Detect](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/touchevents.js) with link and references in comments.

Comment: Reference? Test case?

Comment: See the [modernizr test](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/touchevents.js) long history there.

Answer (score 2):

I ended with:

```
window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mobile') !== -1;
```

Chrome adds `Mobile` to userAgent in device emulation mode, for example "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 **Mobile**/14E5239e Safari/602.1"

> 'TouchEvent' in window && 'ontouchstart' in window

isn’t providing correct state in real time when you turning on/off device mode unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

As Alex mentioned the correct state in real time when turning on/off device is not effected with hexalys answer.

so what I did is like so

- Checking if the browser is lying about its identity - fingerprintjs has a method [getHasLiedBrowser](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs/blob/925b8982aff09fca50c0afe1613a767a3281175f/fingerprint2.js#L1201) that uses browser features to detect browsers by availability of global functions for example.
- Checking if touch device - using hexalys answer does not give indication in real time toggle between device emulation like Alex mentioned so I used this code from other SO answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51774045/14238203
- Checking that `navigator.maxTouchPoints === 1` this indicates we are in simulation mode  (I am not 100% certain, this needs to be checked in Desktop/Laptops with touch screens)
- Using Alex answer for specific edge case, Chrome in emulation of Android devices does not lie, it is still chrome :) So we use Alex answer to cover this case.

```
const isBrowserSimulation = () => {
    // maxTouchPoints is always = 1 on simulation mode
    return (
        isTouchDevice() && // https://stackoverflow.com/a/51774045/14238203
        navigator.maxTouchPoints === 1 &&
        // Alex solution finding 'mobile' in UA covers `getHasLiedBrowser` missing emulation on android devices
        (getHasLiedBrowser() || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mobile') !== -1)
    );
};
```

This solution works in real time toggle of mobile emulation on Chrome per my tests with Chrome, Edge and Brave latest versions.