# Detect when the device emulation mode is turned on or off in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Chrome DevTools has the option to use the device emulation mode.

I know there's a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420123/2890610) to test whether the mode *is* on or not. But I'd like to know when it's being *activated* or *deactivated*, on click.

Are there any events I could listen to, fired by the browser, that indicate the mode was turned on or off?

Comment: A robust solution would probably want to monitor resize events, a changing devicePixelRatio, a changing userAgent, the availability of touch mode detection, and orientationchange and make a decision based on all of them. These signals can mean other things.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing this:

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function(e) {

    if (e.tagret && e.target.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
        // Emulation mode activated
    } else {
       // Emulation mode deactivated
    }

});
```

Works for Google Chrome (my version: 58.0). Is it the bulletproof way? Not sure. It's enough for my needs, though.

`orientationchange` docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange).

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var emulationModeActivated = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mobile') !== -1;
    }, 0);
});
```

Chrome adds `Mobile` to userAgent in device emulation mode, for example "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 **Mobile**/14E5239e Safari/602.1"

`e.target.devicePixelRatio` isn't usable on Mac with Retina Display as value is always > 1

Comment: For switch on mode it certainly true! But for switch off, code should be place into 'resize' event. Thanks @Alex